# Error while stopping windows service in Components Services

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am working on Windows Service. It works fine. When i am trying to stop the service from services.msc, it throws the following error:

Windows could not stop the xxx service on Local Computer. The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.
If I try to stop it again, it takes lots of time and then throws the error as below:

Windows could not stop the xxx service on Local Computer. Error 1061: The service cannot accept control messages at this time.

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        EventViewerHelper.LogMessage(Resources.AppName, Resources.EventViewerServiceFinished, EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);

            string configExchangeURL = Properties.Settings.Default.ExchangeURL;

            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                string UserName = args[0];
                string Password = args[1];
                string Domain = args[2];
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(UserName, Password, Domain);
            }
            else
            {
                service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            }

            service.Url = new Uri(configExchangeURL);
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.None;

            AppSettingsReader settings = new AppSettingsReader();
            bool exchangeDownloadStreamSubscription = (bool)settings.GetValue("ExchangeDownloadStreamSubscription", typeof(bool));
            if (exchangeDownloadStreamSubscription)
            {
                StreamingSubscription streamingsubscription = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox }, EventType.NewMail);
                var connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 30);
                connection.AddSubscription(streamingsubscription);
                connection.OnNotificationEvent += connection_OnNotificationEvent;
                connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
                connection.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
                timer.Interval = 120000;
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventViewerHelper.LogMessage(Resources.AppName, string.Format(Resources.EventViewerServiceStartedError, ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: in your initialiser of your service have you set `CanStop = true;`

Comment: If `exchangeDownloadStreamSubscription` is true, it looks like `timer` is never initialized, so you'd be looking at a `NullReferenceException` during `Stop` for that case (and, obviously, you're not trying to do any other kind of shutdown for the true case either). But don't know which "mode" your service is currently running in.

Comment: this happens when exception is thrown in OnStop. Just add try catch and remember that logging can throw exceptions too